# z3py, list functions declared in a datatype

Tags: python, z3, z3py

```
from z3 import *

record = Datatype("record")
record.declare('cons', ('f1', BoolSort()), ('f2', BoolSort()), ('f3', BoolSort()))
record = record.create()

tmp = Const('tmp', record)

data_type = tmp.sort()  # get the sort of the tmp var, which will be "record"
functions = data_type.functions  # returns the list of functions declared in "record" [cons, f1, f2, f3]
```

How can I get the list of declared functions from a sort? Please look at the last line of the code.

Comment: `import *` is considered back practice.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `constructors` field, here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3py_8py_source.html#l04711

Note that by overwriting the value of `record`, you painted yourself to a corner. It's best to keep the names explicit if you want to do this level of programming. That is, call the data-type a different name, and when you `create`, assign it to a different name. This way you can easily keep track of the datatype and sort. Here's your example coded more clearly:

```py
from z3 import *

record_dt = Datatype("record")
record_dt.declare('cons', ('f1', BoolSort()), ('f2', BoolSort()), ('f3', BoolSort()))
record_sort = record_dt.create()

functions = record_dt.constructors
print functions
```

This prints:

```
[('cons', 'is-cons', (('f1', Bool), ('f2', Bool), ('f3', Bool)))]
```

This gives you the name of the constructor (`cons`), the recognizer (`is-cons`), and names and sorts of all the fields (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`), which you can then use as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @alias! Is it possible to get the information without accessing record_dt? For example, getting it from the instance you created. r1 = Const('r1', record_sort), then somehow get the function from just r1?

Comment: Also, how can I get the function object instead of just the function name? Because if I want to add a constraint f1(r1) == True, I have to have the actual f1 function right?

Comment: You can use the `accessor` function to get access to field functions: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_datatype_sort_ref.html#ab1e6a00a4f728cebe361b23c4f6b2e93 To get access from the object, you'll have to extract the sort, and go through that machinery yourself. Doable, but not recommended. Also, stack-overflow comments are best for simple clarifications; please ask a new question for new topics.